# ASP.NET Razor Page - How do I redirect user if they try to access invalid URL?

Tags: c#, .net, routes, url-routing, razor-pages

I have .NET 7 asp.net razor pages app, I want when somebody types "/invalidUrl" to get redirected to 404 Not Found custom page that I created. I can't find a solution. Can somebody tell me if it's possible?

I tried to add this but it doesn't work.

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/*", "/NotFound");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use StatusCodePages middleware to control what happens when a page is not found: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/configuration/custom-errors.

I would recommend against redirecting someone to your customer error page. That will send a 302 response code back, You should send a 404 status code, which will tell search engines to drop the incorrect URL from their index. That will happen if you use the WithReExecute option:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/notfound");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Viktor
I think all you need isto use RedirectToPage helper method.

For example

`return RedirectToPage("Errors/Error404");`

And you also need to change:

`public void OnGet()`
To

`public IActionResult OnGet()`